# Switch in expandable listview

Tags: android, kotlin, expandablelistview

I have an Expandable List View with some groups that contain a Switch in its child view. So, when I select one switch button from one group, then other buttons from same group should not be selected. I am trying to find the solutions but I didn't find it so if anyone knows how to do it.

**Adapter Class**

```
override fun getChildView(
   groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int,
   isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup
): View {

     var convertView = convertView
     val childText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String
     if (convertView == null) {
         val infalInflater = this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null)
     }
     val txtListChild = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem) as TextView
     val switch = convertView.findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchView)
     val count = getChildrenCount(groupPosition)
     switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->

     }

     txtListChild.text = childText
     return convertView
}
```

Comment: Try: 1. In the adapter, create an integer array with size of number of groups; 2. In switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener, if compoundButton is checked, save the child position to the integer array and call notifyDataSetChanged(); 3. In getChildView, switch.setChecked(true) if childPosition is same as the corresponding value in the integer array, else switch.setChecked(false); Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you sir its working...but what about in all groups?. now i have to select only one item in all the group lets suppose in 1st group item 1 is select all the other items in other group should be false....

Comment: Change the array into 2 integers. Save both group and child position inside OnCheckedChangeListener. In getChildView, `switch.setChecked(true)` if both groupPosition and childPosition equal to the stored integers, else `switch.setChecked(false)`.